# How do I encrypt Video Files in Amazon S3 Storage for Video Streaming?

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, video-streaming, privacy

**Possible Doing**

While Netflix uses Amazon S3 for Video Streaming, they tend to use encrypted video files and stream it as it is. How we can encrypt video files so it is secured against video piracy and others.

**What I want to achieve**

Most of the content is stored in a compressed and encrypted format and streamed as is. They are compressed using a lossy audio/video codec such as MPEG or H. 264. The compressed data is encrypted using a Digital Rights Management system.

How myself can encrypt the video files and stream it with iframe for websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways that a person can stream videos and secure.

- Origin blocking (Origin, CORS, Referrer)
- Embed busting
- Tokenized URLs
- Generic token
- Advanced user specific tokens
- Login/Paywall
- Stream encryption
- DRM (Digital Rights Management)

There are Modern Techniques like.

- Domain filtering
- Referrer filtering
- Embed buster
- Session token
- AES encryption.

  Link might be helpful for you to secure the video streaming service using Nginix. https://gist.github.com/mrbar42/09c149059f72da2f09e652d4c5079919

Comment: Is there any official documentation available for most of them, and does these actually promotes privacy